# No detener solicitudes AJAX al recargar pagina

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un archivo csv que posee bastantes registros (40.000), lo leo con js y lo convierto a un array donde lo fragmento para realizar diferentes llamadas ajax.
mi duda va por un lado de conceptos. 
Resulta que al ser mucho registros las llamadas ajax demoran un buen tiempo, y me gustaría poder abandonar esa pagina y que los procesos que ocurren en el backend con php sigan corriendo ya que ya fueron llamados, pero cuando detengo la pagina se cancelan las solicitudes ajax y con esto los procesos, siendo que a mi modo de ver, no debería afectar ya que son dos procesos que van por cuenta aparte, espero salir de esta sin un cron.

Así que mi primera duda es como lograr que esas solicitudes no se cancelen cuando detenga la pagina, espero que el usuario pueda cerrar la pagina y no por elle se cancelen los procesos. y segundo si es que se logra resolver lo primero, como lograr recargar la pagina sin esperar a que las solicitudes terminen, ya que el reload no se ejecuta hasta que termina al menos 1 de las 6 solicitudes (que punto aparte están llenando datos en una planilla excel).

```
function callService(filename) {
    var arraySend = [];
    arrayCsv.splice(0, 1);
    var size = Math.ceil(arrayCsv.length / 6);
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        arraySend = [];
        arraySend = moverElementos(arrayCsv, arraySend, size);
        $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "index.php/tools/neitcomProcess",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'dataArray': arraySend, 'filename': filename },
            cache: false
        }).done(function (res) {
            console.log(res);
        });
    }
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Pero... ¿Te da lo mismo la respuesta del lado del servidor? (esto es, no necesitas que haya terminado de procesar el CSV) Que se supone que hace el backend cuando recibe ese CSV? Lo guarda en un archivo y el front simplemente asume que se generó?

Comment: Exacto, me da lo mismo, es un proceso que demorará +1 hora (no puedo mantener al usuario esperando ahí y si cierra la pestaña no pueden cancelarse las solicitudes), tengo otras formas para saber si el backend termino. El backend llama a un webservice y con datos que este retorna se genera un excel.

Comment: Lo mejor es que el csv lo procese directamente del lado servidor así aún que el usuario cierre pestaña o navegador el proceso seguirá su curso. Otra cosa es que sea recomendable o realmente necesario, en pocos casos me he visto en los que un usuario en tenga que subir ese número de registros. Se necesitarían más detalles para buscar la mejor forma de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Depende del motor de backend que estés usando para procesar las llamadas a PHP. Yo uso nginx con php-fpm y uso [fastcgi_finish_request](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php) de la siguiente funciona:

```
  ... acá defino si recibí bien el archivo ...

  ob_start();
  echo "Archivo Recibido";
  $content = ob_get_flush();
  fastcgi_finish_request(); // Se termina el request y se envía la respuesta

  ... acá proceso el archivo
```

Comment: Acá se usa IIS, existe alguna alternativa para ello?